# AngularJS: ngRoute no longer serves from wwwroot when fixing hash-bang

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, routes, asp.net-core, location-provider

I started out with this code, `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('myProject', ['ngStorage', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "loginController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/index.html"
        }).otherwise({
            controller: "loginController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/views/login.html"
        });
    });
```

If someone visited -

`http://localhost:8885`

it would redirect to `http://localhost:8885/#!/` and show the `index.html` template the `$routeProvider` had declared.

And if someone visited either -

`http://localhost:8885/#!/asdfasdfasdf` or `http://localhost:8885/#!/1234`

the pages would load and show the `/views/login.html` template.

**Everything was working fine.**

Then, to exclude the `hash-bang`, known as (`/#!/`), I added:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to the end of the `config` mentioned above.

This caused my project to no longer serve my `src -> MyProject -> wwwroot` folder files anymore, but rather the content inside of my `src -> Views -> App -> Index.html` file. File structure shown below:

[image: Visual Studio ASP.Net]

Why is this the case? How do I solve this to not only exclude the `hash-bang` but also to serve from my `wwwroot` folder?

**EXTRA INFO** -

My `_Layout.cshtml` file has this for a body:

```
<body ng-view>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

I've also tried to place `<base href="/">` inside the `<head>` but it didn't work.

Any help?